# Optimization program to allocate time series in 2 groups

Tags: time-series, clustering, optimization, partitioning

I am trying to dispatch $m$ time series into 2 groups. Then I want to sum the value for each time steps, to obtain a sum per group.

My goal is to minimize the standard deviation of the difference between the 2 groups.
In other word, there can be an offset between the 2 groups but they need to vary simultaneously.

More mathematically assume that one has $m$ time series of length $n$ points. $$x_i^g, i \epsilon [0,n], g \epsilon [0,m]$$
I want to find $y_g \epsilon \{-1,1\}$ such that $ Var(z_i) $ is minimized with $$ z_i = \sum_{g} y_g*x_i^g = \sum_{y_g=1} x_i^g - \sum_{y_g=-1} x_i^g$$

Is there any algorithms that I could use?
I am working with python, my current option is to use scipy and implement this custom objective.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The obvious (and standard) approach is to center the time series.

In your case, you may actually want to try double-centering the data.